# Android animation using radio button

Tags: android, animation

I created one animation in which I used one radio button as object and a matrix background. when the activity starts the object will move along the each cells in the matrix. now I want the object to be stopped when i click on it. how can i do this??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RadioButton rad;
Animation animation1;
Context context = this;
Button move;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable handlerTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    rad = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    // move=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
    // userInputHandler();

    /*
     * move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { // TODO Auto-generated
     * method stub
     */
    handlerTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (rad.isChecked()) {
                animation1.cancel();
            } else {
                rad.startAnimation(animation1);
            }

        }

    };

    handlerTask.run();
    // }
    // });

}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    rad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
}
```

Comment: Please try radiobutton_group.setOnCheckedChangedListener

Comment: where should i use it.. and how to use it?

Comment: I think problem is with implementation of Radio button .You have to take Radio Group and inside that take Radio button in layout file

Comment: See this http://androidexample.com/Radio_Button_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=78&aaid=102

Comment: but i used only one radio button who cn i create radio group for it

Comment: To use its click events you need to take radio group though you have taken just one radio button

Comment: how can i use background music when object moves to each cell.. it should be short tone like beep.. every time when it changes the cell i want background music